# Stop tab bar refresh on back button in jquery mobile 1.3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm running JQM 1.3.1 + JQ 2.0

I have a listview (no scroll) of about 60 elements + a fixed footer (tabbar). If I click on one element of my listview, it shows some content in a new hash page where I've added a "back" button.

The active button of the tabbar is set when populating the listview.

When I click on the back button, the previous page shows up but the active button from the tabbar is not active anymore (none of the buttons are active). Which makes me think that all the elements on the first page have been refreshed.

How can I prevent the elements from being refreshed and to keep their state on a "back" call ?

```
    <div data-role='navbar' id='kms'>
      <ul id='kml'>
        <li id='l5'><a href='#' id='d5' class='ui-btn-active'>Ici</a></li>
        <li id='l20'><a href='#' id='d20'>5 km</a></li>
        <li id='l50'><a href='#' id='d50'>20 km</a></li>
        <li id='l100'><a href='#' id='d100'>50 km</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your JS code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the class ui-btn-active from the tab bars.
And write your own customized css class for active and passive tabs.
It worked for me.This may help.

```
.footer-passive a
{
background: #99ce3e ; /*light green*/
}
```

*for active buttons*

```
 .footer-active a
{
 background: #709630;/*dark green*/
}
```

Well then try using below code snippet.

```
<div data-role="footer"  data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li class="footer-color-active"><a href="sample1.html"  class="ui-btn-active"><img src="your_file/path1" /></a></li>
            <li class="footer-color"><a href="sample2.html" ><img src="your_file/path2"  /></a></li>
            <li class="footer-color"><a href="sample3.html" ><img src="youtr_file/path3" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your answer. I haven't succeeded to remove the ui-btn-active yet. I called removeClass('ui-btn-active') on all the buttons but to no effect. The default comes back when I click on the button.

Answer (score 2):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/6h7gn/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $(document).on('click', '#kml li', function(){ 
        var selectedLi = $(this);
        $('#kml li').each(function( index ) {   
            var loopLi = $(this);
            if(loopLi.find('a').hasClass('ui-btn-active')) {  
                $(this).find('a').removeClass('ui-btn-activ').removeClass('ui-state-persist');
            }
        });         
       selectedLi.find('a').addClass('ui-state-persist');        
       setTimeout(function(){
            $.mobile.changePage( "#second", { transition: "slide"});
        },100);
    });       
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My second page doesn't have a navbar. But using 'ui-state-persist' and using toggleClass On/Off on each button worked !

Comment: BTW, I found out that addClass()/removeClass was twice faster than toggleClass().